# Ubuntu 10.04 Keyboard and Mouse Freezing Problem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, acpi

I had a partition setup with Windows XP and Ubuntu 8.04 dual booting.  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 by installing fresh from CD but leaving the previous /home folder as is.  Things seemed to be working fine, but started finding that my mouse and keyboard were freezing.

After a quick search on the internet, I found the following suggestions as shown here:- [Ubuntu Forums](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564683)

Here the suggestion was to:-

> Edit /etc/default/grub, go to the line
> that begins like:
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
>
> Change it to:
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet
> splash acpi=off"
>
> After that, run this command: sudo
> update-grub
>
> and Reboot

This seemed to have resolved the issue but after a couple of days I again find my mouse and keyboard freezing.  I also find that my parallel port printer had also stopped working.

I have saved the output of dmesg and my syslog. The first can be viewed [here](http://freetexthost.com/35ta5ogne6) but the syslog had too many characters, so if someone can suggest an alternative to freetexthost, I can post it there.  Moreover, if there is any other information that should be provided, do let me know.  I do hope we can get to the bottom of this issue.

Thank you in advance for any help that could be provided.

Comment: Do you have a PS2 Mouse/keyboard? If yes, you're most likely suffering from known bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/554527 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powernowd/+bug/110394 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/632048 and several (similar) others.

Comment: The mouse is USB but the keyboard is PS2.  Does the mouse get affected by a PS2 keyboard even though the mouse itself is not PS2?  So would you say that by removing the PS2 Keyboard, then this should be resolved?

Comment: I should add that there were no issues whatsoever with Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy)....its only presented itself in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

Answer (score 0):

You could try backing up all of your dot files, deleting them, and seeing if that fixes the problem. If it does, add them back one by one until the problem presents itself again.

Comment: These dot files are the individual application configuration files.  Would deleting all of them present any problems to the running system?