# Ubuntu freezes when gdm starts showing userlist

Tags: boot, gnome, freeze, ubuntu-10.10

I have Ubuntu 10.10 (upgraded from 10.04)
I was browsing in Firefox yesterday, then the PC did a suddenly reset

Once I restarted, everything went normal until gdm begun showing. **Then everything froze and locked when userlist showed**. I could not move mouse pointer nor do anything with keyboard.

***Both, mouse and keyboard work fine***, because this Ubuntu is dual-booting with a Windows XP install which loads/works fine.

Here is my .xsession-errors file, but I don't have a clue what may be wrong. Thanks

http://pastebin.com/GVtneEAF

Comment: This sounds like a question for either superuser.com, unix.stackexchange.com or AskUbuntu.com

Comment: Please check if the computer freezes or only the input devices. For further info (and links to bug reports) see these questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11316/ps-2-devices-stop-working-in-10-10-release http://superuser.com/questions/190759/ubuntu-10-04-keyboard-and-mouse-freezing-problem

Comment: Does it do this every time you boot into Ubuntu? Even after the computer "cools down"?

Answer (score 1):

I would not rule out a hardware problem.

A while ago, I had a similar problem that showed up days after I had upgraded from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.4: I could still login and even open an application or two, and then suddenly keyboard and mouse would lock up, but the applications would keep running, music or videos would keep playing, running downloads would keep running, etc. However, I could boot an older Ubuntu live CD without noticing any lockup. I was frantically searching for a driver problem. Then I noticed that I could get the computer to lock up simply by running a memtest86 stress test, and a few days later my motherboard finally died.

Answer (score 0):

Try narrowing down the problem by going into tty from the login screen with
ctrl-alt-f1. Kill gdm with "sudo service gdm stop"

Then start the x server as root with "sudo startx"
This will bypass gdm. If this doesn't work, you know it's a problem with the x server,
and if it does, it's a problem with gdm.

Once you've narrowed down the problem, you can use apt to reinstall gdm (assuming that's the
problem) or install kdm and KDE to bypass gdm.

I'm afraid I don't really know what to do if the problem's with the x server...

Comment: can't do anything at gdm screen because (as title says) everything freezes

Comment: do you notice something in the .xsession-errors file?